# Fully Ajax driven JSP Web App ? Template/Skeleton inside.. Any flaws?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee

Ive thought of creating a fully ajax-driven Webapp. There should be absolutely no submits/full page reloads.

The login is done by checking the user/pw in a bean, and setting the appropriate redirect

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<style>
.ui-widget {
font-size: 12px !important;
}
</style>

<title>myApp</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="mainform">

    <ui:include src="#{navigationBean.currentPage}" />

</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The navigationBean always contains the currently valid page for the User session (SessionScoped Managed Bean). If something changes i will update the "mainform" via the corresponding ajax-capable components, or use f:ajax.

As for now everything is working as expected but did i miss something?

Is there a major drawback by using this solution? What should i be careful of?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: How exactly would this not have page reloads?  The <ui:include> tag is  processed by the JSP compiler server side so to change the content after the first include, would it not need to round trip back to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a javascript-solution that already goes in that direction, like [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) [angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) or [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/)

**For your solution, you have to consider:**

--> I think 1, and 4 are the most problematic parts:

*1: URLS*

- What happens with the URL? This is important considering bookmarks and the browser's back button. Therefore you should rewrite the url (jQuery can do that easily with `window.location.hash`) with #-values.
- e.g. you should not keep `your-domain.com/app` for all sub-pages, but change the URL to `your-domain.com/app#sub-page-1`
- When loading the page you can parse the #-value and directly load the content tied to that url.

This is important for a good user-experience. Reloading a page and being returned to the home-page sucks! Sharing links without that is just not possible.

*2: Data and Templateing*

In your case `<ui:include src="#{navigationBean.currentPage}" />` will load another jsf-page in your main-page. So you are loading a template + data via ajax.

Another possible approach would be to just load the data from the server and use JavaScript to put the data and templates together. This technique is getting quite popular right now. (JavaScript Frameworks like angular.js do that.) This has disadvantages too, because your page will be very JavasScript-heavy and you'd pretty much abandon JSF with that.

*3: Loading JavaScript and CSS*

If you have sub-pages with additional CSS- or JavaScript-Files, you should check if you can load them via ajax (it's generally possible, but requires some work). If not, you have to load all related files on the first request of the page, which can make the initial loading slower.

*4: Storing the current page in a bean*
I think that is not necessary, if you use *1.*  With the bean (SessionScoped?) storing the current page, this has some disadvantage:

- If you are on a sub-page and type in the URL to get to the home-page, it will load the old sub-page.
- This will cause conflicts if you are browsing your site with 2 or more tabs.

**Conclusion**

After writing this, I think it's not a good idea to store the current page in a bean. As it will cause conflicts. I would recommend to "store" the current page in the url.

Something like this:

```
  <div id="nav">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="sub-page-1">sub-page-1</a>
  </div>
  <div id="main"></div>
```

JavaScript w/ jQuery would be something like this:

```
     $(function() {
          $('#sub-page-1').click(function() {

                  $.ajax({
                         ...
                         url: '/sub-page-1' // could be jsf page
                         success: function (data) {
                               // set the hash of this page
                               window.location.hash = 'sub-page-1';
                               // set the content on the main div
                               $('#main').html(data);
                         }
                  });

          }) 

     });
```